# Dependency injection in a class not working on a worker service

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, worker

Is there a way to DI something into a class?

For example,

I have a .net 6 worker service that looks like the following:

Startup:

```
IConfiguration builder =
    new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);

        services.AddScoped<MpwContext>(
            serviceProvider =>
            {
                return new MyDBContext(builder.GetSection("MyDBConnectionString").Value.ToString());
            });
    }
```

Worker.cs:

```
      public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IMapper mapper)
        {
            //All the constructor stuff here
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            var partService = new PartService();

            await partService.DoSomething();
        }
```

PartService:

```
       public PartService(IMapper mapper, MyDbContext myDbContext)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _myDbContext = myDbContext;
        }

        public async Task DoSomething()
        {
        }
```

The issue I am facing is where I say : `var partService = new PartService();`  It is telling me that I am missing all the paramters in the constructor.

`There is no argument given that corresponds to the required field MyDbContext and mapper....`

I know with mvc the constructors pick up on the DI stuff on its own, how can I do that in this case?

The Databases are scoped so I cannot consume them directly in the worker, so I need to DI them in to each respective service. But its asking for them on the object creation.

Comment: "The issue I am facing is where I say : var partService = new PartService();  It is telling me that I am missing all the paramters in the constructor." - yes, because that's trying to construct it directly, without using DI. Can you not make your workers scoped as well, and just inject the `PartService` into the `Worker` constructor? It feels like we're missing quite a lot of context here. But you shouldn't expect DI to just "magically" get involved when you call a constructor *directly* in code.

Comment: @JonSkeet  sorry if there is some context missing. Still very new to DI and its mechanics. So a class has to be added as a singleton etc to be able to use the injected context?

Comment: @JonSkeet my issue is that the worker cannot take a scoped service. Since the worker is a singleton. This is a .net 6 service worker and it tells me that the scopes differ, and that a scoped service cannot be consumed by a singleton

Comment: I'm not an expert in DI either, so others may be able to help you more... but what's calling `ExecuteAsync`, and has it created a new scope in which to have a worker? If you could provide a [mcve] it would be much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Reference [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task)

Comment: Ill try add a replicatable example. The excecuteasync is triggered by a timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it.

It's normal for background services to be singletons (and thus only allow singleton dependencies). By default, there's no DI scope within `ExecuteAsync`, but you can [create your own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task):

```
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

public Worker(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IMapper mapper)
{
  _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
  ...
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

  // Not working yet:
  var partService = new PartService();
  await partService.DoSomething();
}
```

The other thing you need to know is that the .NET DI is rather simple-minded. The common pattern is to explicitly register every single type you need, including types that only have a single constructor:

```
services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
services.AddSingleton(mapper);

services.AddScoped<MpwContext>(
    serviceProvider =>
    {
      return new MyDBContext(builder.GetSection("MyDBConnectionString").Value.ToString());
});
services.AddScoped<PartService>();
```

Now that you've defined `PartService` as a scoped service, you can ask the DI to create an instance for you:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

  var partService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PartService>();
  await partService.DoSomething();
}
```